# Colocar ArrayList en una Tabla o ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero poner un ArrayList que dentro de una tabla o un listview

lo importante es que pueda sumar algúna colúmna de mi tabla

```
productos =(ArrayList<Producto>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

ese es el ArrayList que quiero colocar.

Esta es mi clase Producto:

```
public class Producto implements Serializable{
String nombre;
double precio;

public Producto(String nombre, double precio) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    String nombre1;
    nombre1=this.nombre;
    return nombre1;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    double precio1;
    precio1=this.precio;
    return precio1;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {

    this.precio = precio;
}

public double total(){
    this.precio=precio+precio;
    return this.precio;
}}
```

Y este es mi main donde recibo mi ArrayList:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);
    ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    productos = (ArrayList<Producto>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");


    lista = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla);
```

Comment: hay una infinidades de tutoriales, videos en youtube sobre este tema. Que ha intentado usted hasta ahora?

Comment: @sioesi ya edite mi código con lo que he hecho hasta ahora

Comment: "lo importante es que pueda sumar algúna colúmna de mi tabla" a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: @sioesi osea como si existiera una columna que dice precio, todos los elementos que estan en esa columna se sumen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder llenar un ListView con un diseño propio debes hacer lo siguiente :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Aqui dentro de tu layout declaramos un elemento listview, para agregarle diseño personalizado, que no se lo que quieres en tu caso particular es por eso que no dare estilos ni posiciones, debes hacer lo siguiente :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" /> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/precio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Luego creamos una clase, que soporte a tu Modelo por ejemplo

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
    String nombre;
    double precio;

    public Producto(String nombre, double precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        String nombre1;
        nombre1 = this.nombre;
        return nombre1;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        double precio1;
        precio1 = this.precio;
        return precio1;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {

        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public double total() {
        this.precio = precio + precio;
        return this.precio;
    }
}
```

Luego tienes que crear un adaptador para tu lista

**EDIT 1**

> Un adaptador es un objeto que comunica a un ListView los datos
>   necesarios para crear las filas de la lista. Es decir, conecta la
>   lista con una fuente de información como si se tratase de un adaptador
>   de corriente que alimenta a un televisor.
>
> Además de proveer la información, también genera los Views para cada
>   elemento de la lista.
>
> Los adaptadores se representan programáticamente por la clase
>   BaseAdapter. Dependiendo de la naturaleza de la lista se elegirá un
>   adaptador prefabricado en el SDK de Android o extenderlos para
>   satisfacer tus necesidades.

[Pagina fuenta de la cita](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/)

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Producto> productos;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Productos> productos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productos= productos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.productos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.productos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // Create a new view into the list.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Set data into the view.
    TextView precio= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.precio);
    TextView nombre= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);

    Producto producto = this.productos.get(position);
    precio.setText(producto.getPrecio());
    nombre.setText(producto.getNombre());

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Y en tu activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    productos = (ArrayList<Producto>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    this.listView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(this, productos));
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Para lo otro que necesitabas, que era sumar un valor de tu lista, te recomiendo sumarlo en una funcion extra. Que puedas llamarla desde tu modelo y mostrarlo graficamente.

```
public intgetTotal(ArrayList<Producto> productos){

    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<productos.size();i++){
        total= total + productos.get(i).getPrecio();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Edite mi código para que veas bien como esta mi clase

Comment: Porque no entendi muy bien el adaptador @sioesi

Comment: @J.Torres puedes adaptar mi codigo y agregar tu clase

Comment: @J.Torres El adaptador es una coleccion que queremos mostrar en una vista. Cuando quieres llenar una lista de una forma particular tienes que decirle COMO y DONDE va a mostrar tu coleccion de datos.

Comment: @J.Torres edite mi respuesta, espero que puedas comprender mejor

Comment: Si me crea la lista pero no me aparece los nombres de lo que quiero agregar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46944/discussion-between-sioesi-and-j-torres).